# SilverStripe 3.5 - Fluent leads to 404 errors on translated pages

Tags: silverstripe, multilingual

I'm using **Fluent** with **Fluent Extra Table** to translate my website.

My fluent.yml looks like this:

```
---
Name: myfluentconfig
After: '#fluentconfig'
---
Fluent:
  default_locale: de_DE
  disable_default_prefix: true
  detect_locale: true
  remember_locale: true
  locales:
    - de_DE
    - en_US
  aliases:
    de_DE: de
    en_US: en
---
Name: myfluenti18nconfig
After: '#fluenti18nconfig'
---
i18n:
  default_locale: de_DE
```

Accessing the default language (German) is no problem, switching the language also works, but if the page has an changed url segment, I always receive a 404 - not found error.

For example:

- German: domain.tld/kontakt **works**
- English: domain.tld/en/kontakt **works**
- English: domain.tld/en/contact **404 error**

Any ideas how to solve that?

**Edit:**
The translated URLSegment get's in the table `sitetree_en_us` in the column `URLSegment_en_US`. But It seems that SilverStripe is only using the URLSegment stored in the `sitetree` table and that's the "default/german" one.

Comment: are you using the right version of fluent? https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/issues/113

Comment: I've installed it over composer to get the latest version (3.5) on a fresh installed SilverStripe site

Comment: Is the URL segment translated when you view it in each locale in the CMS?

Comment: do you mean that the urlsegment field is translated and saved to the db? yes.

Comment: Can you share your config for how you apply the Fluent extension?